# Spark based application failing in JDK 8?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am running built in sample example which comes as part of Spark installation, and running in Hadoop 2.7 + Spark with JDK 8. However it is giving me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot allocate
>   new DoublePointer(10000000): totalBytes = 363M, physicalBytes = 911M
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Physical memory usage is too
>   high: physicalBytes = 911M > maxPhysicalBytes = 911M
>           at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.deallocator(Pointer.java:572)
>           at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.init(Pointer.java:121)

I followed the following SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467761/how-to-know-what-is-the-reason-for-closedchannelexceptions-with-spark-shell-in-y) as well, and did the configuration changes.

In addition to this, I referred to these links as well: [YARN-4714](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-4714) , [HADOOP-11090](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11090)

Are there any issues in running Spark in JDK 8.

The below are the versions of the softwares that I am running in my simple cluster:

> jdk-8u131-linux-x64
>   scala-2.12.2
>   spark-2.1.1-bin-without-hadoop
>   hadoop-2.7.0

One thing when I run the program in JDK 7, it is working fine, but failing with JDK 8.

Has anyone encountered this problem and if so, what is the fix? Isn't hadoop , spark, scala not yet compatible with JDK 8?

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Java 8 has no constant pool, try increase Xmx on JVM 8

Comment: @T.Gawęda: Thanks for your comments, could you please elaborate a bit further?

Comment: Sorry - it was PermGen ;) Article about change http://karunsubramanian.com/websphere/one-important-change-in-memory-management-in-java-8/

Comment: Thanks for your info!

Comment: Can you try to increase the memory by setting the below in spark-defaults.conf                                                                                                                               spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Xmx1024M
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -Xmx1024M

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving OOM error is the indication of shortage of memory for java to launch. As you have mentioned JDK7 it worked fine. Upgrading to JDK8 require more memory compare to JDK7. Please check JDK8 memory requirements here - https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace

Answer (score 0):

Spark is not yet released for Scala 2.12. I don't know if it solves the original problem but you should switch to Scala 2.11 anyway.

Comment: Where is this mentioned? Can you please share the link?

Comment: Spark maven repo: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark
There are no artifacts for scala 2.12.
Related ticket in Spark Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14220

Comment: You can refer https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html in Note section Note: Starting version 2.0, Spark is built with Scala 2.11 by default. Scala 2.10 users should download the Spark source package and build with Scala 2.10 support.